# Is there a way to use source generators with .net framework 4?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, sourcegenerators

I am trying to use StrongInject in the .NET 4 project. But the thing is that I am getting `Package StrongInject 1.2.1 is not compatible with net40`. However, my own roslyn analyzer works fine and they both the analyzer and the generator target to netstandard2.0. Googling didn't help much. Could anybody clarify this?

[image]

Comment: I would think no as one of the requirements for `StrongInject` is `.NET 5.0.102 SDK or greater`.

Comment: Maybe it is time to update your target?

Comment: I just want to keep the lib I'm working on as generic as possible. SDK is installed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't SourceGenerators - it's the Stronginject library itself (the part you reference like any other library). That targets .NetStandard, which is only compatible with .Net Framework 4.72 or later.